# Animation on UIButton Click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, core-animation

Everybody..
How to set animation on button click ?

I have two buttons, both have different frame..

```
First   CGRectMake (10 , 10 , 100 , 80 ); It has Black Image,
Second  CGRectMake (200, 10 , 210 , 80 ); It has White Image,
```

When I click on First button of those, It should be animate to move from one frame to another frame..

Only seen like first's button Black Image move to second button location.. Like Image changes of Buttons..

After clicked button frame does not change... Should be remain as First and Second..

I have tried but not got the exact

```
buttonFirst.frame = buttonSecond.frame;
buttonFirst.center = buttonSecond.center; 
buttonFirst.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( buttonSecond.frame.origin.x - buttonFirst.frame.origin.x , buttonSecond.frame.origin.y - buttonFirst.frame.origin.y);
```

How to animate this ?

Editting :

I need to move one checkers from one CGRect to Another CGRect.. So, It want to display like moving checkers, But i dont want to change CGRect, Only button images looks like that...

Please tell me..
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer...

I have set two button in two separate view. after set one timer, and move first button image to another button's position..
Here is a sample code for that..

Step 1 : Set view with Timer

```
UIView *oldView = [[UIView alloc] init];  
                    oldView = [viewArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
                    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
                    newView = [viewArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
                    oldRect = [oldView frame];                    
                    newRect = [newView frame];
                    movingTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
                    movingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(movingCheckers:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

                    imageViewMove = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
                    [imageViewMove setFrame:oldRect];
                    [imageViewMove setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:blackManName]];

                    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageViewMove];
                    [self.view addSubview:imageViewMove];
```

Step 2 : Moving Image to second position

```
CGPoint aPoint = CGPointMake(newRect.origin.x - oldRect.origin.x, oldRect.origin.y - newRect.origin.y);                    
imageViewMove.frame = CGRectMake(imageViewMove.frame.origin.x + (aPoint.x / 6) , imageViewMove.frame.origin.y - (aPoint.y / 6), imageViewMove.frame.size.width, imageViewMove.frame.size.height);
if (imageViewMove.frame.origin.x >= newRect.origin.x)
{
                [selectButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
                [moveButton setBackgroundImage:imageViewMove.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageViewMove removeFromSuperview];
                [movingTimer invalidate];
}
```

Now its work.....

Answer (score 0):

well..
you can try this link

```
[UIView beginAnimation/endAnimation] bock
```

Comment: yes, Also.. Here is a code.. UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
                    [imageView setFrame:button.frame];
                    [imageView setImage:buttonS.currentBackgroundImage];
                    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.0];
                    [imageView setFrame:buttonS.frame];
                    [UIView commitAnimations];
                    [imageView removeFromSuperview]; But not worked..

Answer (score 0):

Here is example from working program:

```
    [self.buttonFirst setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.buttonFirst
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                animations:^{ 
                    buttonFirst.frame = buttonSecond.frame;
                    buttonFirst.center = buttonSecond.center;
                     }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [self.buttonFirst setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];                         
                }];
```

Comment: in section with `animations` set `buttonFirst.frame = buttonSecond.frame;` And it will be working.

Comment: I have just edited code, this must be working. in `options` you can set animation options.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect oldRectFirst = buttonFirst.frame;
CGRect oldRectSecond = buttonSecond.frame;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    buttonFirst.frame = oldRectSecond;
    buttonSecond.frame = oldRectFirst;
}];
```

Comment: Ok, i guess i understand. Check it now

Answer (score 0):

very simple logic

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.20f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[firstButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 30, 30)];//moves to second button place 
[secondButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30)];//moves to first button place
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

use the logic accordingly to your use..